# How to execute bash function as command?

Tags: bash

I have a CLI tool that needs to be called the following way:
`foobar run -- [command]`
For example
`foobar run -- script.sh`

The problem is, that I want to install the CLI tool in the same shell script. How can I do this with the following structure?

```sh
# My script I want to run with the CLI tool
perform_actions () {
   # ...
}

# Installing CLI tool from some URL
# ...

# Execute my script with the CLI tool
foobar run -- perform_actions  # This doesn't work because perform_actions is a function
```

Comment: I don't think it will matter even you use a separate script instead of a function. Does your foobar run needed to be piped to something or does it read the output of the action?

Comment: Is this legitimate - `foobar run -- script.sh arg` - then you just make the script differentiate between "install" time and "run" time based on command line args.

Answer (score 0):

I would organise script this way :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
SCRIPT_SH=$(cd $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE);pwd)/$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)

# My script I want to run with the CLI tool
perform_actions () {
    # ...
}

foobar_run(){
    foobar run -- $SCRIPT_SH perform_actions
}

# Installing CLI tool from some URL
# ...

# Execute my script with the CLI tool
# foobar run -- perform_actions  # This doesn't work because perform_actions is a function

"$@"
```

To run the script :

```
./script.sh foobar_run
```